# Centroid of bounded region.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Given a closed $n-1$ dimensional object: $x_1 \dots x_n = f_1(t) \dots f_n(t)$, what is the centroid of the $n$ dimensional region it encloses?

Comment: What does it mean by $x_1 \dots x_n = f_1(t) \dots f_n(t)$

Comment: for the low dimensional special cases, it could be a curve enclosing an area, or a surface enclosing a volume (the special condition is that its parametrically defined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $i$th coordinate is $\displaystyle\overline{x^i} = \frac{\displaystyle\int_R x_i \,dV}{\displaystyle\int_R \,dV}$.